# how to get the current viewing div/div(s) in view port with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there any way i can get the current visible div in the view port from jquery/js?

Suppose my html page is like this:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id = "bodyDiv">
   <div id="div1">div1 div content</div>
   <div id="div2">div2 div content</div>
   <div id="div3">div3 div content</div>
   <div id="div4">div4 div content</div>
   <div id="div5">div5 div content</div>
   <div id="div6">div6 div content</div>
   <div id="div7">div7 div content</div>
   <div id="div8">div8 div content</div>
   <div id="div9">div9 div content</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Suppose `div3`, `div4` and `div5` are in view port but i dont know about it. Is there any way i can get that info from jquery or from JS?

[image]

Comment: @Jeto i am sorry as far i understood, do we have to pass the div id to the function to check if it s visible or not right? i dont want to pass any id, i have to get an idea what all divs are there in view port thats it

Comment: this can help https://codepen.io/BoyWithSilverWings/pen/MJgQqR

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper to add or remove a class like this

```
function findAll(selector, callback) {
    //let nodesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector)); 
    let nodesArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    if (typeof callback == "function") {
        callback(nodesArray);
    } else {
        return nodesArray;
    }
}

function intoViewport(elements, classNames, callback) {
    findAll(elements, function(els) {

        document.addEventListener("scroll", intoView, false);
        window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
            intoView();
        });

        function intoView() {
            els.forEach(function(el) {

                var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
                var elemTop = rect.top;
                var elemBottom = rect.bottom;

                // Only completely visible elements return true:
                //var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
                // Partially visible elements return true:
                var isVisible = elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;

                if (isVisible == true && typeof callback == "function") {
                    el.classList.add(classNames);
                    callback(el);
                } else {
                    el.classList.remove(classNames)
                }
            })
        }

    })
}
//intoViewport(".color", "active", function(e) { console.log(e)})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's rare I plug one of my own libraries but I wrote one a while back that seems to do what you need. It's used in production so it should be reliable.

First of all you give your HTML elements a couple of classes:

```
<div id="div1" class="gocek pct-50">div1 div content</div>
<div id="div2" class="gocek pct-50">div2 div content</div>
<div id="div3" class="gocek pct-50">div3 div content</div>
```

`gocek` registers the element with the library (it's called gocek.js). `pct-50` tells gocek to notify you when the element becomes at least 50% visible (or invisible, as required). You can change this percentage to anything you like; so to check if an element is fully visible (or invisible), you'd use `pct-100`.

Then the JavaScript:

```
gocek.on('visible', 'div', () => alert('callback')); //<-- all DIVs
gocek.on('visible', '#div3', () => alert('callback')); //<-- specific DIV
```

Should you want to listen for invisibility rather than visibility, you can change the first param to 'hidden'.

[Here's a fleshed-out Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pm3s7gab/2/) and [here's the unminified source code](https://tuitionkit.com/assets/js/gocek.js).

I regret that there's no proper documentation for it currently, but the Fiddle should guide you enough.